# python, flask uploading image method cannot completed

Tags: python, flask, file-upload

I am trying to code an upload image page in python flask web application. Here is upload.html:

```
<body>
    <h1>file uploader</h1>
    <form id="upload-form" action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
    <input type="file" name="file" accept="image\\*" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</body>
```

and here is my upload method in application.py

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'images\\')
    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)
    for file in request.files.getlist("file"):
        fileName = file.file_name
        destination = "\\".join([target,fileName])
        print(destination)
        file.save(destination)

return render_template('upload.html')
```

I call upload method from home.html as

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('upload') }}">upload</a>
```

This code creates the images folder but does not add the image to the folder. It cannot goes into 'for file in request.files.getlist("file"):' loop.
I cannot recognize what causes to this problem?

Comment: what is the output of `print(destination)`?

Comment: `<input type="file" name="file" accept="image\\*" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="send">` between `<form>...</form>` tags

Comment: It cannot execute the for loop so I do not know output of the  print(destination)

Comment: @waynetech thank you so much for your helpful idea.

Answer (score 0):

When I change

```
<form id="upload-form" action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
<input type="file" name="file" accept="image\\*" multiple>
<input type="submit" value="send">
```

to

```
<form id="upload-form" action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" accept="image\\*" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

and change

```
fileName = file.file_name
```

to

```
fileName = file.filename
```

my problem solved successfully. Thank you @waynetech so much :) .